# How to exclude a model field from the create view in flask-admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a `User` model with a password field. I want the password to be auto-generated when I create a `User` row. I figure I can generate the password in `on_model_change` but for that to happen I need to exclude the password field from the default create view.

I have tried `column_exclude_list = ['password']` but it only exclude password from the list view.

Comment: You need to explicitly set the [form columns](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.form_columns). e.g. `form_columns = ('name', 'email')`. In your case you want to leave out the password field.

Answer (score 1):

```
  form_excluded_columns = ['password']
```

will exclude the password column from the create view.